# Running Rails module from Command Prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, ruby-on-rails-3.2, command-prompt

I have a module like this in my Rails application. I have a folder extras inside my app folder. Inside that i have a module.

```
module ExcelUpload
 class Eupload
   def do_something
   end 
 end

 def self.excel_upload
   upload_service = Eupload.new
   upload_service.do_something 
 end  
end
```

How to execute this above module from command prompt. I want to execute like rake tasks. 
Eg - bundle exec rake db:migrate

Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 0):

module name should be the camel casing name of the folder in which you are keeping the .rb file. Here it should be `module Extras` instead of `module ExcelUpload`

suggest you to put that module in your `\lib` folder of your application's directory structure. From there you can simply access it like `Extras::Eupload.excel_upload` from your console

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `Rakefile` and prepend it with the below, then you can have access to rails from anywhere:

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require APP_PATH
# set Rails.env here if desired
Rails.application.require_environment!
```

Answer (score 0):

create a rake file `your_task.rake` inside, `/lib/tasks`

inside this `your_task.rake`:

```
namespace :your_task_name do
  desc "Description About your task"
  task :task_name => :environment do
    # Write all your task here
  end

end
```

now run this task from terminal:

```
rake your_task_name:task_name
```

It's simple right. :)